# UV and IR cutoff in massless quantum scalar field hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, regularization

I'm writing my bachelor's thesis and working on Srednicki's discussion about area laws for a massless scalar quantum field with Hamiltonian
The field is in a spherical lattice of discrete points with spacing a;
The UV cutoff is thus $a^{-1}$ and the IR cutoff is $L^{-1}$ where $L=(N+1)a$

The starting Hamiltonian is
$$H=\sum_{lm}H_{lm}$$
where
$$H_{lm}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty [\pi_{lm}^2(x)+x^2(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\varphi_{lm}(x)}{x}))^2+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^2}\varphi_{lm}^2(x)]$$

then as an ultraviolet regulator, replace the continuous radial coordinate x by a lattice of discrete points with spacing a; the ultraviolet cutoff M is thus $a^{-1}$ . As an infrared regulator, we put the system in a spherical box of radius
L =(N+1)a, where N is a large integer, and demand that $\varphi_{lm}(x)$ vanish for x$\geq$L; the infrared cutoff $\mu$ is thus $L^{-1}$
The paper says that altogeter this yields

$$ H_{lm}=\frac{1}{2a}\sum_{j=1}^N \bigl[\pi_{lmj}^2+(j+\frac{1}{2})^2\bigl(\frac{\varphi_{lmj}}{j}-\frac{\varphi_{lm(j+1)}}{j+1}\bigr)^2+\frac{l(l+1)}{j^2}\varphi^2_{lmj}\bigr].$$

$\textbf{I do not undestand where did Srednicki put the UV and IR cutoff to get the last Hamiltonian}$

Comment: Maybe you should share more details --- what are you supposed to calculate with the Hamiltonian?

Comment: I'm supposed to compute the entropy for the scalar field, i edited the question with the explicit expression of the Hamiltonian and where I need to get